# Can I use PHP HTTP_REFERER to display a special message?

Tags: php, http-referer

I have two domains which are similar,

mysite1.com and mysite2.com

I only have one hosting account and I have the other site forward (through GoDaddy) to the one hosting account.

I want to display a message to users who come to the site from mysite2.com url.

I was thinking I could use PHP HTTP_REFERER to do so.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4909443/using-php-serverhttp-referer-to-display-custom-welcome-messages-content/4909452#4909452 Probably has the answer you look for. Not a dupe, but close.

Comment: Can you change the redirect to include a special flag in the url? HTTP_REFERRER is an optional header sent by the browsers, so it won't be as reliable.

Comment: What have you tried already? If you're a programmer and can read [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), I'm sure you can make something of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(preg_match('@mysite2\.com@i', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
  print 'Special message!';
}
```

Comment: wouldn't `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` be a more appropriate variable to use in order to determine the domain the visitor is **currently** on?

Comment: @Dutchie432: I think it's a single HTML page hosted by GoDaddy which redirects to the actual site, so `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` does not tell a difference. I've seen other hosts doing the same, GoDaddy might do the same thing. But other than than, you're right.

Comment: It's not a single page. It's domain forwarding which brings the user who enter mysite2.com to mysite1.com. You're script didn't help me :(

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `HTTP_REFERER` will tell you where the user was PREVIOUS to the current page. I think you are looking to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` instead. This will always yield the domain the user is **currently** on... `mysite1.com` or `mysite2.com`